# How can we get .msg attachment file?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to check if the mail i get have an `.msg` attachment file, so when i try to parse my mailbox, it's recognized as an mail and not as an attachment file

I tried to get every type of attachment file, but it doesn't work

```py
mBoxes = mail.list()
mail.select("INBOX")

result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
ids = data[0].split() # data is a list.
for email_id in ids:
    fstab.write("\n")
    result, data = mail.fetch(email_id, "(RFC822)") # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
    email_body=data[0][1]
    listattachments=[]
    m = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)
    for part in m.walk():
        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join("/home/nguyen/Documents/SPAMS/", 'attachments', str(len(listfilename))+fileName )
            if not os.path.isfile(filePath)  and ".jpg" not in fileName and ".p7s" not in fileName and ".png" not in fileName and "@" not in fileName :
                listfilename.append(fileName)
                listattachments.append(fileName) #Check number of attachments per mail
                fstab.write(filePath+"\n")
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```

I expect to get .msg file attachment too, but the script read the file attachment as a mail directly

Comment: are You using any specific libraries ?

Comment: I use imaplib and email